# Black Screen while triyng to install Lubuntu 20.04

Tags: boot, system-installation, uefi, lubuntu, usb-installation

I'm triyng to install Lubuntu 20.04 in an Sony Vaio SVS1311F3EW (specs Intel Core i5-3210M and graph card Intel HD Graphics 4000)

BIOS setup is UEFI

I've tryed both DVD and USB boot.

Any option I choose in the boot menu, I get a black screen.

I've already tryed "nomodeset" in GRUB's linux line.

I made the USB boot with etcher (but I tryed with Start Disk Creator and unetbootin as well)

Can anyone help?

Comment: Have a look into the boot-devices. Some laptops give you 2 options, one the with the usb mounted into UEFI-mode, one with standard USB-access. See that the one with UEFI is selected. If the problem persists, try another distro.

Comment: The only options the BIOS offers is to enable or desable external device boot. I've already tried Linux Lite, Puppy Linux and Kubuntu as well.

Comment: Did the media check complete successfully?   Why do you mention `nomodeset`, the option I'd try is "*Start Lubuntu (safe graphics)*" if the normal "*Start Lubuntu*" didn't work.  Did you download the ISO from Ubuntu or Lubuntu?  (*your choice makes me wonder, as google can send people to unofficial sites offering download*). Why not write the ISO as Lubuntu recommends, ie. https://manual.lubuntu.me/stable/1/1.2/booting_the_image.html

Comment: Did you validate your ISO?  In the Lubuntu manual it's mentioned at https://manual.lubuntu.me/stable/1/1.1/retrieving_the_image.html though normal Ubuntu procedures (https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu#0) apply to all *flavors* too

Answer (score 0):

Edit the kernel boot parameter to include :
`acpi_osi=!` <--This should work just fine.

You may include: `quite`, `splash`, `nomodeset`

Do not use `acpi=off`. It may work at first but give you problems later.